Convergence of gaussian filtered function
Consider the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ and the standard Gaussian filter $K_{\delta}(x) = \frac{1}{\delta \sqrt{2\pi}} e^{\frac{x^2}{2 \delta^2}}$. I am interested in finding out how fast the filtered function $f*K_{\delta} $ converges to the true function $f$ in $L^1$ and $L^2$ on an interval $[a,b]$ for $a,b >0$. This would correspond to evaluating:
$$ \int_{a}^{b} \bigg| \frac{1}{\delta \sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}} e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{2 \delta^2}} dy - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \bigg| dx$$
$$ \int_{a}^{b} \bigg| \frac{1}{\delta \sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}} e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{2 \delta^2}} dy - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \bigg|^2 dx$$
as $\delta \rightarrow 0$ and finding out the order of these integrals as a function of $\delta$.
Any reference or help is appreciated.

How did you derive this? In my view this difference should go zero, not to $1/\sqrt{x}$. See here

How did I derive this? Too quickly ;) My mistake, will look more carefully now...

The convolution integral can be expressed as a pair of Bessel $I$ functions, from which one finds for fixed $x$, that $f*K\sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\left(1+\frac{3\delta^2}{8x^2}\right)$ as $\delta \to 0$

Can you post the computations so that I can award you the points?

Let $f*K_\delta=\frac{I(\delta)}{\delta\sqrt{2\pi }}$ so that
$$\tag{1}
I(\delta)=\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{dx'}{\sqrt{x'}} e^{-(x-x')^2/2\delta^2}
$$
Changing variables $u=x-x'$ fixes the maxima of the integrand at $u=0$, then
$$\tag{2}
I(\delta)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^x \frac{du}{\sqrt{x-u}}e^{-u^2/2\delta^2}
$$
Using a CAS, (2) can be evaluated exactly$^\dagger$, but we can derive the asymptotic $\delta\to 0$ behavior using Laplace's method for fixed $x$. We will need the first two terms in the series (see eg. Bender and Orszag chapter 6 for the general details). In the present case this just corresponds to Taylor expanding the non-exponential bit about the maxima $u=0$
$$\tag{3}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-u}}\sim\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}+\frac{u}{2x^{3/2}}+\frac{3 u^2}{8x^{5/2}}\qquad,\qquad u\to0
$$
Then performing the Gaussian integrals
$$\tag{4}
\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty du \ \left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}+ \frac{3 u^2}{8x^{5/2}}\right]e^{-u^2/2\delta^2}=\delta\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{x}}+\delta^3\frac{3\sqrt{2\pi}}{8x^{5/2}}
$$
So that
$$\tag{5}
I(\delta)\sim\ \delta \sqrt{2\pi}\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}+\frac{3\delta^2}{8x^{5/2}}\right]\qquad ,\qquad \delta\to 0
$$
$$\tag{6}
f*K_\delta \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\left[1+\frac{3\delta^2}{8x^2}\right]\qquad,\qquad \delta\to 0
$$
$\dagger$ The exact result is
$$\tag{7}
I(\delta)=\frac{\pi\sqrt{x}}{2}e^{-z}\left[I_{1/4}(z)+I_{-1/4}(z) \right]
$$
Where $I_\nu$ is a modified Bessel function of the first kind, and $z=\frac{x^2}{2\delta^2}$. Then we recover (5) using the large argument expansion
$$\tag{8}
I_\nu(z) \sim \frac{e^z}{\sqrt{2\pi z}}\left[1+\frac{4\nu^2-1}{8z} \right]\qquad, \qquad z\to \infty
$$
